# What happens to my background thread when the tablet goes to sleep

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tablet

I am making a c# Windows app for a tablet that polls looking for a bluetooth device. Say I do this on a background thread using a timer. When the tablet goes to sleep, does this background thread get paused or does it continue to run and eat resources? What if the polling is done on a ui thread?